# Please explain Vim's configuration directories hierarchy

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to update my `Vim` configuration scripts. There are a number of sub-directories in my `~/.vim` directory and I'm not sure the specifics of what they do, nor why there are some that seem to be redundant.

Here is what my `~/.vim` directory tree looks like

```
 |-after
 |---ftplugin
 |---syntax
 |-autoload
 |-compiler
 |-doc
 |-ftplugin
 |---latex-suite
 |-----dictionaries
 |-----macros
 |-----packages
 |-----templates
 |---python
 |-indent
 |-plugin
 |-spell
 |-syntax
```

Now for the specific questions.

1. What goes in `plugin` vs `ftplugin`?
2. What is the difference between `plugin` and `autoload`?
3. When should I put something in `after/...` instead of in the directories directly under `~/.vim`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Whatever goes into `plugin` is loaded whenever vim starts whereas what you put in `ftplugin` is only loaded for the specific filetype it corresponds to (so if you have a folder there called python all the files there will be loaded when you open a python file.
In `autoload` you should have the functions corresponding to the the scripts defined in `plugin`. The functions here will only be loaded when called by the first time.

In `after` you should put settings that you want to change from the normal plugin loading.
As an example suppose you like the settings that some plugin for latex gives you, but it redefined a mapping that you had in your `.vimrc`. You can revert this with autocommands or by putting the correct definitions in after.

Comment: Thanks @skeept. If I understand correctly, put the main plugins into `plugin` or `ftplugin`, supporting things in `autoload` and stuff to override everything else in `after`. Correct?

Comment: If you are doing something that applies to a specific filetype you should go with ftplugin. For something that applies to all filetypes put in plugin but if possible try to load it in autoload, and yes whatever is in after overrides everything else. I think the link provided in the answer by Eduan is a good resource, you should read it.

Answer (score 15):

I think this would explain exactly what each folder does: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html

Also might want to check `:h runtimepath`.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: very helpful link. it's a complete book on vimscript for serious people.

Answer (score 10):

All those directories are part of the `runtimepath`. Try `:h runtimepath` and it will link you to your answers:

1. Check `:h write-plugin`
2. Check `:h autoload-functions`
3. `after/...` scripts are executed last, so they can override settings of earlier scripts. You can read more about this in `:h runtimepath`.

Comment: I like this answer as well because it shows the built-in Vim help to see how to write a plugin, and structure it.