# Neovim autoloaded folders

Tags: neovim

Im currently running:

```
✗ nvim -v
NVIM v0.3.0
```

I use plug.vim to load plugins, and I like to keep plugin configs in separate files instead of having everything in init.vim:

```
✗ pwd
/Users/mwaldner/.vim/plugin

✗ ls
ale.vim               fzf_config.vim        strip_whitespace.vim
commentary_config.vim reload_files.vim      vim-go.vim
```

I've moved to a new laptop, and installed the latest version of neovim. It seems like the plugins folder is no longer autoloaded like they are in regular vim. I've had to manually source all my configs file which isn't a big deal, but just curious why that changed.

What folders get autoloaded in neovim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

See [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14248335/8812461), most importantly `:help runtimepath`.

Summary: Vim provides a transparent directory schema that is defined by when you want things to load. For example, `autoload/` contains scripts you source before anything else and whose functions you can use in your `.vimrc`, and `ftplugin/` is dedicated for filetype-specific configurations.